# App freezes after sending text to Facebook, using SLComposerViewController or UIActivityViewController if there is no internet connection

Tags: ios, facebook, freeze, uiactivityviewcontroller, slcomposeviewcontroller

I have trouble when sharing a text to Facebook using `SLComposerViewController` or `UIActivityViewController`. When users press the done button the app freezes if there is no internet connection. It only happens with Facebook, other services are ok.

I'm using Xcode 6.4 and it happens on iOS 8.3 and 8.4.

```
SLComposeViewController* vc = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [vc setInitialText:name];
    [vc addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];
    vc.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
            refSelf.shareFailed(@"");
        }
        else {
            refSelf.shareSuccess();
        }
    };
    [[self getRootViewController] presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Are you still having this issue? Did this same code work before 8.3? Also can you provide a screenshot or a more detailed example on how to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Yes, I'm still having this issue. Maybe this is an issue from Apple. The app freezes in iOS 8.1 and 8.4. It seems like app freezes until there is an internet connection.